# How to use jQuery validate from scope variable (after webpacking)

Tags: jquery, npm, scope, webpack, jquery-validate

TLDR;
**Is there a way to use jquery-validate after i bound jquery and jquery-validate to the window scope? or is there a possibility to bundle them via webpack before putting them into the scope?**

---

Atm i'm working on a rather large project with loads of views etc

as i didnt want to oversize the header with scriptfiles i bundled them up with webpack (1.13.0)

since i use jquery, axios and lodash frequently i bound them to the window scope in the layout template, to be able to use them in the view templates without reloading jquery etc all the time

so if i need jquery in a specific view, i grab it from the scope like

var $ = window.Tools.$;

now i tried to use jquery validate..

the regular usage reads something like

*edit: whoopsi stackoverflow ate my scripttags*

```
  <script src="./script/jquery.min.js"></script><br>
  <script src="./script/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
```

i never used jquery plugins before, so ive no idea how to use it in the way i handle jquery at the moment

any hints?

My little scopescript atm looks something like this:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import $ from 'jquery';
import moment from 'moment';
import _ from 'lodash';
import jQvalidate from 'jquery-validation';

window.Tools = {
 $,
 moment,
 axios,
 _,
 jQvalidate
};
```